# Java lambda callback in clojure

Tags: java, lambda, clojure, jvm, interop

I use a java library in clojure and it has a function that accepts a callback:

http://home.dv8tion.net:8080/job/JDA/Promoted%20Build/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/entities/MessageChannel.html#sendMessageAsync-java.lang.String-java.util.function.Consumer-

How do I pass such callback in clojure? I tried anonymous function `fn` but it doesn't work. In java using java lambdas works.

Comment: hyperlink is broken

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply [reify](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reify) an interface.

Here is an example

```
(def consumer (reify java.util.function.Consumer
                (accept [this t]
                  ; here the impl 
                  )))
```